# Are Proofs of Dependent Pair Types Equivalent to Finding an Inverse Function?

Tags: predicate-logic, type-theory, intuitionistic-logic

Since $\Pi_{(B:A\rightarrow\mathcal{U})}\Sigma_{(a:A)}B(a)$ is the type theoretic way for expressing $\forall B:A\rightarrow\mathcal{U}.\exists a \in A. B(a)$ and one often has to work backwards to figure out what $a$ is supposed to be in a proof, would a proof of $\Pi_{(B:A\rightarrow\mathcal{U})}\Sigma_{(a:A)}B(a)$ be equivalent to finding a certain function of type $(A\rightarrow\mathcal{U})\rightarrow A$?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. $B(a)$ doesn't need to be a function type. For your "proof of the converse of $B(a)$", where is this $a$ coming from? A proof of $\Sigma a:A.B(a)$ is a pair consisting of a value $x$ of type $A$ and a value $b$ of type $B(x)$. This is very roughly like having $\{x\in A\mid B(x)\}$ except that there may be multiple values for $B(x)$. A proof of $\Pi b:B.\Sigma a:A.f(a)=b$ would roughly be asking for a pre-inverse of $f$.

Comment: I just realized that the converse on product types does not make any sense, I updated my question.

Comment: $B$ isn't a type, it is a function $A\to\mathcal{U}$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is the universe, i.e. the type of "types". $B\to A$ is just an ill-formed expression like writing $3\to A$.

Comment: @DerekElkins I updated my question.

Comment: Okay, in a constructive framework (and type theory doesn't need to be constructive in general, though often *intuitionistic* type theory is intended), then yes, the proof object for that type would contain a function $f:(A\to\mathcal U)\to A$ as well as another function of type $\Pi B:A\to\mathcal U.B(f(B))$ providing proofs. These are just the function $\Pi B:A\to\mathcal U.\Sigma a:A.B(a)$ followed by the two projections of the $\Sigma$ type.

Comment: Added intuitionistic-logic tag.